# when "reconvene" collocate with meeting(or conferencen), should it be uesed in passive voive or active vioce?

Tags: active-vs-passive

> e.g1: After a 20-minute hiatus, the press conference **was reconvened**.   --quote from The New York Times
>
> e.g2:The Conference Committee **will reconvene** to resolve differences between
> the last House and Senate versions of the following     --quote from
> hawaii.gov

when reconvene collocate with meeting, board, conference or something same. what voice should "reconvene" to be used in? passive or active? in eg1 it is passtive, but in eg2 it is active, why?

Comment: Have you looked up "reconvene" in any dictionaries? What did you find? The first one I checked made it clear that "reconvene" is both *transitive* and *intransitive*, which means both those sentences are correct.

Comment: You should call them "example 1" and "example 2".  *e.g.* is an abbreviation that means something like "here is an example", but you can't replace the word *example* with *e.g.*.